# Use case for the new Extract / Exclude conditional types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

So I’ve used Pick and other built-in types, but I’m struggling to find a use case for `Exclude` and `Extract` - [source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#predefined-conditional-types) - because we only have the ability to pass a union literal as the argument, rather than an object.

Has anyone any insight into the new conditional types such as these for a simple use case? Appreciated!

Comment: You can write a version that takes an object literal as the argument: `type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;`.